# not able to play audio music

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

iam   gatting error $%7Bindex+1%7D.mp3:1 GET/songs/$%7Bindex+1%7D.mp3 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

default  song(1.mp3)  is playing but when i select another song it give error

```
 console.log("Welcome to music player");
//initialize the Variables

let songIndex = 0;

  const audioElement = new Audio('songs/1.mp3');
let masterPlay = document.getElementById('masterPlay');
let myProgressBar = document.getElementById('myProgressBar');
let gif = document.getElementById('gif');

let masterSongName = document.getElementById('masterSongName');
let songItem = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItem'));
 songs = [
    { songName: "closer - chainsmokers", filePath: "songs/1.mp3", coverPath: "1.jpg" },
    { songName: "a thousand years", filePath: "songs/2.mp3", coverPath: "2.jpg" },
    { songName: "Let me love you", filePath: "songs/3.mp3", coverPath: "3.jpg" },
    { songName: "someone you loved", filePath: "songs/4.mp3", coverPath: "4.jpg" },
    { songName: "Let me down slowly", filePath: "songs/5.mp3", coverPath: "1.jpg" },
    { songName: "stay - Justin beiber", filePath: "songs/6.mp3", coverPath: "1.jpg" },

]

  songItem.forEach((element,i) => {
   
      element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src=songs[i].coverPath;
      element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[0].innerText=songs[i].songName;
  
  })

masterPlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime <= 0) {
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-play-circle')
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-pause-circle')
        gif.style.opacity = 1;

    }
     else {
        audioElement.pause();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-play-circle');
        gif.style.opacity = 0;
    }
})

audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',()=>{
   
      progress = parseInt((audioElement.currentTime/audioElement.duration)*100);
  
    myProgressBar.value=progress;
})
myProgressBar.addEventListener('change',()=>{
   audioElement.currentTime  = myProgressBar.value * audioElement.duration/100;
})
const makeAllPlays = ()=>{
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=>{
        element.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
        element.classList.add('fa-play-circle');
    })
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=> {
    element.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        console.log(e.target);
        makeAllPlays();
```

given id to every one in html now taking in index

```
      index = parseInt(e.target.id);
        e.target.classList.remove('fa-play-circle');
        e.target.classList.add('fa-pause-circle');
```

// for playing every song

```
   audioElement.src = 'songs/${index+1}.mp3' ; // error generating on this line
   console.log(index);
   
   
   masterSongName.innerText=songs[songIndex].songName;
   audioElement.currentTime=0;
   audioElement.play();
   
   masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
   masterPlay.classList.add('fa-play-circle');

 } )

})

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click',()=>{
if(songIndex>5){
    songIndex=0;
}
else{
    songIndex+=1;
}

audioElement.src = 'songs/${index}.mp3';
masterSongName.innerText=songs[songIndex].songName;
audioElement.currentTime=0;
audioElement.play();
masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
masterPlay.classList.add('fa-play-circle');

})


document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click',()=>{
if(songIndex<=0){
    songIndex=0;
}
else{
    songIndex-=1;
}

//audioElement.src = 'songs/${index}.mp3';
masterSongName.innerText=songs[songIndex].songName;
audioElement.currentTime=0;
audioElement.play();
masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
masterPlay.classList.add('fa-play-circle');

})
```

Comment: What's the error, please?

Answer (score 0):

Because you've used the single quote `'` instead of the back tick `. Since you didn't use the back tick, the code didn't use your variable

So you should change that line to:

```
audioElement.src = `songs/${index+1}.mp3`;
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).